# `app.route` and `template_render` not working in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm learning Flask and I created two routes :

1. "/about" : was routing a template as render.template(about.html)
2. "/aksh" : was routing a template as render.template(index.html)

It worked for `index.html` and not `about.html` and when I made changes in `index.html` and refreshed nothing happened.
I tried restarting everything including my system.

Then I commented that route "/aksh" but too much of my surprise portaddress/about was showing no url found whereas portaddress/aksh was still showing the text .

After that I re-edited whole code , now in new code there are 3 routes :

1. "/" : return a print statement "Hello World!"
2. "/aksh" : render a template `index.html`
3. "/about" : render a template `about.html`

But this has made no change now also I'm getting old results the new routes are not getting updated.

My python code is :

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World"
@app.route("/aksh")
def aksh():
    return render_template('index.html')
@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')
app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML codes for index and about are :
index.html :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title of my page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>We are testing flask app here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

For about.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>About this page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is about section</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Its showing "we are testing app" but it must be "we are testing app **here** " and moreover its in wrong location it must be in route "/aksh" not "/"
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you saved your files. Try hard reload by pressing shift+f5. It is better to run app in if name == main scope. https://www.codementor.io/@overiq/basics-of-flask-fzvh8ueed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve this issue .
The problem was 1st I runned this code via PyCharm and then by Python interpreter IDLE (obviously after closing pyCharm) and somehow PyCharm was still controlling the server even after system restart .

So after checking everything and getting now clue I just powered off my system completely and started again and then run the application via IDLE only thus solving all issue !

So the conclusion was :
->PyCharm was still controlling the server even after system restart.
->Power off and on solved the issue for me .

Sounds weird but that's how it worked .
If anyone here can explain why PyCharm was still controlling servers even after restart would be better .

Answer (score 0):

Use separators to solve this problem.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
app=Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World"


@app.route("/aksh")
def aksh():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')


app.run(debug=True)
```